# start numbering of abstract as page ii rather than page i

Tags: numbering, abstract, page

I'm trying to change the starting count (page number) beginning with the abstract to "ii" instead of "i". With the code below, the page number for the abstract is "i" at the bottom of the page. I would like it to read "ii" and continue counting from there. (The title page is the real "i" but that number is correctly suppressed.)

This is for a dissertation. Thanks!

MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{scrbook}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
[some text]
\end{titlepage}

\doublespacing
\frontmatter

\chapter{Abstract}
[some text]
\chapter{Acknowledgments}
[some text]

\newpage

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\begingroup
\renewcommand\numberline[1]{}
\listoftables
\endgroup

\newpage

\listoffigures

\mainmatter

\include{1.intro}

\include{2.litreview}

\include{3.decentralization}

\include{4.cases}

\include{5.data} 

\include{6.Districts1997to2007Mozambique}

\include{7.SouthAfrica}

\include{8.BroadAfricaEmpirical}

\include{9.conc}

\backmatter

\bibliographystyle{myauthordate1}
\bibliography{library}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Add `\stepcounter{page}` right before `\chapter{Abstract}`.

Comment: Just for clarification: the difference between my comment and AML's answer is that `\stepcounter` adds 1 to the given counter, and `\setcounter` sets it to a specific value.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE, Zack. Your MWE is not exactly "minimal" ;D you can search for "someone just asked me to make a minimal working example" on meta.tex.stackexchange.com to learn what everyone is talking about. hagt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `\setcounter{page}{2}` before `\chapter{Abstract}`.

Comment: If this is the solution, then upvote and also accept as the answer.

Comment: Can I accept both answers? They both worked. I don't know how to upvote.

Comment: Click on the up arrow to upvote. Click on the checkmark to accept answer.

Comment: @Zack My answer was in a comment. You cannot "accept" it.